# how to create PDF file using html format in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf-generation

I'm having a student form in which I took data from editText and stored it in variables and I want to generate a pdf of that form using HTML and I'm confused where to place the HTML file in android studio I don't have any issue about generating pdf I have issue about using HTMl file
I used below code to generate pdf using html.

```
val document = Document()
    // write the document content
    val targetPdf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/mypdf.pdf"
    val filePath:File
    filePath = File(targetPdf)
    var writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
        FileOutputStream(filePath))

try
{

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,FileOutputStream(targetPdf))
    document.open()

    var htmlcontext=HtmlPipelineContext(null)
    htmlcontext.setTagFactory(com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory())

    var cssResolver:CSSResolver=XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false)
    var pdf = PdfWriterPipeline(document,writer)
    val html = HtmlPipeline(htmlcontext, pdf)
    val ss = CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html)
    val worker = XMLWorker(ss, true)
    val p = XMLParser(worker)
    val s = ByteArrayInputStream()
    document.close()
    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF is created!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.e("PATH",""+filePath.absolutePath)
    openGeneratedPDF()
}
catch (e:IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```